Splitting and calculating across a large RasterStack using Terra in R
I have a rasterstack, created from an .nc file, named 'dat.stack'
> dat.stack
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 180, 360, 28896  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs 
source      : pr_ssp370_2015_01_2100_12.nc:pr 
varname     : pr (Monthly mean of daily accumulated precipitation) 
names       : pr_me~r=1_1, pr_me~r=1_2, pr_me~r=1_3, pr_me~r=1_4, pr_me~r=1_5, pr_me~r=1_6, ... 
unit        :          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm,          mm, ... 
time (days) : 2015-01-01 to 2100-12-01 

This is supposed to be monthly precipitation data from January 2015 through December 2100.
However, we can see there's many more layers than there are months in that period (1032) in the raster.
This is because the file aggregates monthly precipitation data from 31 models.
the layer names are structures like this: pr_member=1_1032, whereby the two numbers after 'pr_member=' represent the model number (1 through 31), then an underscore, then the month number (1 through 1032). So pr_member=14_50 is the precipitation raster for the 50th month from the 14th model.
What I would like to achieve is the following:
I want three rasters per month of precipitation data that show me the following:
-A raster with the mean precipitation across the models
-A raster with the 25th quantile across the models
-A raster with the 75th quantile across the models
I have been attempting this with the below code but it returns empty rasters. I think I may be overlooking a few things as I'm quite new to working with Terra. Perhaps the timestamps attached to the rasterstack could be used to do this more easily? I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with this.
I noticed the number of layers is not exactly what one would expect (31 models x 1032 months = 31992, not 28896) so I suspect there are NAs. Ideally the code would take this into account, so I can figure out if TIF files are written that are based on an incomplete number of models, or TIFs for certain months are missing.
# Extract layer names to identify months
layer_names <- names(dat_stack)

# Extract unique months
unique_months <- unique(as.integer(sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", layer_names)))

# Function to calculate mean and IQR, monthly
calculate_mean_and_iqr <- function(month_layers) {
  # Load layers for the given month across models
  monthly_raster <- rast(month_layers)
  
  # mean
  mean_raster <- mean(monthly_raster, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  # 25th and 75th percentiles
  p25_raster <- app(monthly_raster, quantile, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
  p75_raster <- app(monthly_raster, quantile, probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
  
  list(mean = mean_raster, p25 = p25_raster, p75 = p75_raster)
}

# Process each month
for (month in unique_months) {
  # Get layers for the given month across all models
  month_layers <- grep(paste0("_", month, "$"), layer_names, value = TRUE)
  
  results <- calculate_mean_and_iqr(month_layers)
  
  # Extract year and month from the first layer name (assuming consistent naming)
  yr_mo <- substr(month_layers[1], nchar(month_layers[1]) - 9, nchar(month_layers[1]) - 3)
  
  # Write the rasters to files
  mean_fname <- file.path(out.dir, paste0("mean_", yr_mo, ".tif"))
  p25_fname <- file.path(out.dir, paste0("p25_", yr_mo, ".tif"))
  p75_fname <- file.path(out.dir, paste0("p75_", yr_mo, ".tif"))
  
  writeRaster(results$mean, mean_fname, overwrite = TRUE)
  writeRaster(results$p25, p25_fname, overwrite = TRUE)
  writeRaster(results$p75, p75_fname, overwrite = TRUE)
}


I'm not sure if I did exactly what you expected with the names but, this works, even if some of the spatrasters within the stack are NA or empty.
I tweak the function the create the layer names there so you can simplify later the exportation part.
# Create fictional data
library(terra)

# Set up dimensions and resolution to match your example
n_rows <- 25
n_cols <- 50
n_layers <- 144  
resolution <- c(1, 1)

# Params
out.dir <- "./"

# Create dummy precipitation values (adjust as needed)
precip_values <- runif(n_rows * n_cols * n_layers, min = 0, max = 200) 

# Create an empty SpatRaster with the desired dimensions, resolution, and extent
dummy_raster <- rast(nrows = n_rows, ncols = n_cols, nlyrs = n_layers,
                     xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90,
                     crs = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs")

# Assign the dummy values to the raster
values(dummy_raster) <- precip_values

# Create layer names following the "pr_member=X_Y" structure
member_ids <- rep(1:12, each = 12)
month_ids <- rep(1:12, times = 12)
layer_names <- paste0("pr_member=", member_ids, "_", month_ids)

# Assign layer names
names(dummy_raster) <- layer_names

# Calculate the number of months represented by the layers
n_months <- n_layers / length(unique(member_ids)) 

# Create a sequence of dates starting from "2024-01-01", spaced by months, to match the number of layers
time_seq <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), by = "month", length.out = n_months) 

# Ensure that time_seq is at least as long as the number of layers
if (length(time_seq) < n_layers) {
    time_seq <- rep(time_seq, length.out = n_layers)
}

# Assign the time sequence to the raster
time(dummy_raster) <- time_seq

# Print the raster to verify the structure
print(dummy_raster)

#---Your part---

# Extract layer names to identify months
layer_names <- names(dummy_raster)

# Extract unique months
unique_months <- unique(as.integer(sub(".*_(\\d+)$", "\\1", layer_names)))

# Function to calculate mean and IQR, monthly
calculate_mean_and_iqr <- function(r) {
    # Extract year and month from the first layer name (assuming consistent naming)
    yr_mo <- substr(time(r)[1], 0, nchar(time(r)[1])+2)
    
    # mean
    mean_raster <- mean(r, na.rm = TRUE)
    names(mean_raster) <- paste0("mean_", yr_mo)
    
    # 25th and 75th percentiles
    p25_raster <- app(r, quantile, probs = 0.25, na.rm = TRUE)
    names(p25_raster) <- paste0("p25_", yr_mo)
    p75_raster <- app(r, quantile, probs = 0.75, na.rm = TRUE)
    names(p75_raster) <- paste0("p75_", yr_mo)
    
    return(c(mean_raster, p25_raster, p75_raster))
}

# Process each month
for (month in unique_months) {
    # Get layers for the given month across all models
    month_layers <- grep(paste0("_", month, "$"), layer_names, value = TRUE)
    
    # Create a subset raster containing only layers matching the month
    subset_raster <- dummy_raster[[month_layers]]
    
    # Process
    results <- calculate_mean_and_iqr(subset_raster)
    
    # Export all
    for (r in seq_along(names(results))){
        filename <- paste0(out.dir, names(results)[[r]], ".tif")
        writeRaster(results[[r]], filename, overwrite = TRUE)
    }
}

